# Workbench Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1' (0)

Tags: mysql, wamp, workbench

I've installed the mysql community server, server is running, and i'm able to connect through command line using

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

which is the community server. I've also installed wamp which has its mysql server running on port 3306, the command above also connects to that server again

wamp is running fine and i'm able to get into phpmyadmin just fine, but when i try connecting to either mysql server through localhost using workbench, i'm presented with an error "Failed to connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3307 with user root
Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1' (0)"

I've been searching online for hours now and i can't seem to find any solutions to this. The only problem i'm having is connecting through workbench.

Are there any settings for workbench that i might have to change in order to connect to the servers?

EDIT:
This is all on windows by the way. I've also reinstalled wamp, workbench, and mysql server multiple times

Comment: what does `netstat -a` show for 3306 and 07

Comment: cool, as expected, both are up and listening then